# Feedzirra Not Installed Properly?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-3.2, feedzirra

I'm trying to use Feedzirra in my Rails 3.2 app to do simple feed parsing. I found this online: http://asciicasts.com/episodes/168-feed-parsing. I followed the instructions there to install the gem, but I believe this instructions are somewhat out of date, since it refers to placing a `config.gem` line in my `config/environment.rb` file, which cannot accommodate such calls. I am getting an `uninitialized constant ApplicationController::Feedzirra` error and I'm not sure why.

I put this code in my application controller:

```
before_filter :load_blog_feed

def load_blog_feed
  feed = Feedzirra::Feed.fetch_and_parse(feed_url)
  @blog_posts = feed.entries[0...3]
end
```

I placed this line in `config/application.rb`:

```
config.gem "pauldix-feedzirra", :lib => "feedzirra", :source => "http://gems.github.com"
```

Lastly, I placed this code in a view:

```
<div id="blog_feed">
  <% @blog_posts.each do |post| %>
    <p>
      <span class="post_title"><%= link_to "#{post.title} >>", post.url %></span><br>
      by <span class="post_author"><%= post.author %></span> on <span class="post_date"><%= post.published %></span>
    </p>
  <% end %>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I found the answer... just include `gem 'feedzirra'` in your Gemfile and run `bundle install`. `gem 'pauldix-feedzirra'` doesn't seem to work, though.

Answer (score 1):

For Rails 3.2 , to be more precise, add the following line to **config/application.rb** file :

```
config.gem "feedzirra", :lib => "feedzirra", :source => "http://gems.github.com"
```

and following line to **Gemfile** :

```
gem 'feedzirra'
```

Then run :

```
bundle install
```

Then you can use feedzirra in your application smoothly.

Answer (score 0):

use Bundler!

place

----- EDITED

`gem 'feedzirra'`

into Gemfile, and run `bundle install`